# Differentiation problem of power to infinity by using log property

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Problem:

Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ if $y =\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^{x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}}$

Let ${x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}} =t. (i)$ Taking $\log$ on both sides $ \implies {x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}}\log x = \log t$

This can further be written as $ t
\cdot\log x = \log t$

Differentiating w.r.t. $t$ we get :

$\frac{dx}{dt}=\left(\frac{1-\log t}{t^2}\right)x$. (ii)

Now taking $\log$ on both sides of original equation :

$\log y = {x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}} \log\sqrt{x} \implies \log y = t \log \sqrt{x}$

Now differentiating both sides w.r.t. $x$ we get :

$\frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx} = t\log\sqrt{x} = t \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} + \log\sqrt{x}\frac{dt}{dx}$. (iii)

Now putting the values of $y$, $\frac{dt}{dx} $, and $t$  from (i), (ii) and (iii) we get:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \left(\sqrt{x}\right)^{x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}}\left[\frac{{x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}}}{2\sqrt{x}}+\frac{\log\sqrt{x} \cdot{x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}}}{(1-\log{x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}})x}\right]$$

Please confirm whether it is the correct answer or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

If $y =\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^{x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}}=\left(\left(x\right)^{x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}}\right)^\frac12$

$$\implies y^2=\left(x\right)^{x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}}=(x)^{y^2}$$

Now, taking log wrt $e,$  $$2\ln y=y^2\ln x$$